# counting two events/things as a single event or as distinct different events

Tags: probability

Find probability that first die of two thrown is a 6, given the sum is 8

I counted 6 elements in the sample space (62, 26, 35, 53, 44, 44), but the answer (verified empirically) uses only 5 elements (i.e. the pair of 4s is counted only once).

If 35 and 53 are different, why aren't 44 and 44 (as if one die were red and one were green)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you answered your own question, if one of the dice were red and the other green 4,4 would still be indistinguishable.

Maybe if you ask yourself instead what values ONE of the dice can take, and how many of just that ONE die has acceptable values. It can take values 2,3,4,5,6. It can't take any value twice, including taking the value 4 twice.

Comment: But isn't the "first" 4 distinguishable from the "second" 4?

Comment: Okay say the one of the combinations is the "first" die being 4 and the "second" die being 4. What is the other combination of 4's which can be distinguished from this example combination?

Answer (score 0):

You can distinguish the dice as the first and second (e.g. if you roll the same die twice in succession instead of two dice simultaneously) or as the red die and the green die but not both. Your first 44 can be interpreted as "first die was 4 and second die was 4 too" or "the red die was 4 and the green die was 4 too". The interpretation of your *next* 44 is just the same statement re-ordered, that is, the second 44 is not distinguishable from the first 44: they describe the *same* occurrence.